# From Scanner of File to Array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I would like to ask for some help for this code.
I have no problem reading a File itself and using it as a scanner.
I can easily count the number of doubles the file has.
As an example these are the first five doubles of the txt file.
(These numbers are suppose to be listed vertically, but I hardly doubt that'd make a difference)

> 10     84     39     93     34

I would like to put these doubles into an array, but for some reason instead of putting the double from the scanner into the array, Java only puts in 0.0's.

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

    //This is for finding out the size of the array.
    int nums = 0;
    while(in.hasNextDouble() == true){
        nums++;
        in.nextDouble();            
    }

    double[] list = new double[nums];

    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            list[i] = in.nextDouble();
        }
    }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This code overall just prints "num" amounts of 0.0's instead of adding the actual numbers themselves. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Show us where you print out the array. Also note that you've already read all the doubles by the time you try and add them to the array. Use an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, you are reading all the data before you add it to your array, so when you go to add, there's no data left to read.

Several Different Options:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
int nums = 0;
double[] list = new double[5];
while(in.hasNextDouble()){
    list[nums] = in.nextDouble();
    nums++;            
}
```

Try something more like the above(for a fixed amount of data), you are reading all the doubles before you add them to the array..You can't read through all the data as you are doing just to see how large your array needs to be..unless you make a new scanner to re-read the file

NOTE: The code above assumes your file only has 5 doubles always, it this is not the case perhaps you would want to use an arraylist so the list can expand as you add an unknown quantity of doubles (see example below using arraylist)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
while(in.hasNextDouble()){
    arrayList.add(in.nextDouble());            
}
```

or...after the first while loop is done, just add the lines below again and your original code will work.

```
in.close();
in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

when using the in.nextDouble() you are iterating through your file

lets say your file contains: `1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0`

when you use `in.hasNextDouble()` this function returns true if any value double exist
in our case:
 1.0 then Yes it return true and goes throw the loop

`in.nextDouble();` retrieve the 1.0 double and put the cursor to the next one

Then the loop go to while again to check if there are still Double values using the hasNextDouble() method

.
.

until no next double value is left in the file the application exits the loop

I suggest you try this code

```
        double[] list = new double[nums];
        int nums=0;

        while(in.hasNextDouble() == true){

       list[nums]= in.nextDouble();            
        nums++;

    }
```

the for loop you are having is useless

Answer (score 0):

You've already "scanned" in those numbers, and the internal file position indicator has reached the end of the file when your while loop terminates.  You'll need to close this scanner and re-open it, or open a new one so it can start at the top of the file again.

Answer (score 0):

Your scanner has already read through the file by the time you add all the doubles. You could re-write the code to add them on the fly or just do the less neat solution of re-initialing the scanner before your try block.

```
in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is this.

In the first loop you are going through all the numbers in the file

```
int nums = 0;
while(in.hasNextDouble() == true){
    nums++;
    in.nextDouble();            
}
```

Then you are trying to read more doubles that don't exist (I'm assuming why that's the reason you tried to `try/catch` it, because you were getting  a NoSuchElementExcetion. Instead of trying to hack that problem, you should've been looking for the cause.

Once you loop through an entire file, there will be no more elements to read. So you would have to to close the scanner and open a new one.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

//This is for finding out the size of the array.
int nums = 0;
while(in.hasNextDouble() == true){
    nums++;
    in.nextDouble();            
}
in.close();

double[] list = new double[nums];

in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));   // new scanner
try{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        list[i] = in.nextDouble();
    }
}catch(NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(in.hasNextDouble() == true){
    nums++;
    in.nextDouble();            
}
```

That loop already scanned the numbers from your file.

To fix that, you can figure out how to input the numbers in the while loop above, or create a new Scanner:

```
in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt")); // redefine Scanner "in"
```